# Smoothness for real closed spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Is there a notion of smoothness for maps of real closed spaces in the sense of Schwartz? [1]

Ideally it would have the following properties:

- Every smooth map of real closed spaces is locally of the form $(0,1)^n\times U\to U$;
- For every smooth map of schemes $S\to T$, the induced map of real closed spaces $S_r\to T_r$ is smooth.

(note that all maps $S_r\to T_r$ induced by a smooth map satisfy the first condition, since étale maps induce local homeomorphisms and every smooth map is étale locally a projection)

[1] *Schwartz, Niels*, [**Real closed spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1984-14-4-971), Rocky Mt. J. Math. 14, 971-972 (1984). [ZBL0576.14023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0576.14023).